# Dozer Date mapping

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

I am new to Dozer and I wan to know if is it possible to map date given as:

- String DATE_DAY;
- String DATE_MONTH;
- String DATE_YEAR;

to classic java Date. So I want to map three fields into one. I know you can do DD/MM/yyyy -> Date (String to Date, only one field), but what about this scenario. Thanks for answers.

Comment: I don't think Dozer supports this yet. You can however wrap those fields in a different class, and have an instance of that class as 1 field instead of having 3 fields. Then write custom converter to convert the class object to `Date` instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can only map the class containing those three Strings with a [custom converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html), wherein you implement the mapping manually.